# Taking keyboard input and running checks on it

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following method

```
    public static int modeChooser(){
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(choice == 0){
        try {
        choice = kb.nextInt();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
        if(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
            continue;
        }
    }

    return choice;
}
```

The goal is to only allow the user to put in 1,2,3,4, or 5;
If the user types a string or a too high/low number, the method should just restart until i have the proper int.

Here is an example for the flow:

User types:  1   -> all ok
User types:  saddj  -> method restarts -> user types  3 --> all ok

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
do {

    // read choice value

    if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
        // hint to user
    }

} while(choice < 1 || choice > 5);
```

Comment: I like the do while, it makes the code sleeker. However, where do I put a statement to be executed if the user types an Int of 7? the do while asks again but with no hint to the user as to why.

Comment: See my edit. See an example of menu http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=275

Comment: yeah i figured an if(), thought there might be a more elegant way :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could include your condition on choice directly in the while condition:

```
while(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
    try {
    choice = kb.nextInt();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

(In your current code, is the user enters 7, choice takes that value, the while condition becomes false and your method returns 7, which it should not).

And instead of catching an exception, you could use the `hasNextInt()` method to make the code cleaner:

```
public static int modeChooser() {
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
        if (!kb.hasNextInt()) {
            kb.next();
        } else {
            choice = kb.nextInt();
        }
    }

    return choice;
}
```

If you do want to use a recursive method, it could look like:

```
public static int modeChooser() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!kb.hasNextInt()) {
        kb.next();
    }

    int choice = kb.nextInt();
    return (choice >= 1 && choice <= 5) ? choice : modeChooser();
}
```

Comment: actually 1 is an acceptable value, a string or a non 1,2,3,4,5 number should reset which is what my answer does. thanks thou

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply put your check in the `while` condition itself as below:

```
while(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
    try {
        choice = kb.nextInt();  
    } catch (Exception e) { 
       //ignore the exception and continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way actually works fine:

```
public static int modeChooser(){
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(choice == 0){
        try {
        choice = kb.nextInt();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry but you have to enter 1,2,3,4, or 5! Please try again.");
            choice = modeChooser();
        }

    }
    if(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
        System.out.println("Sorry but you have to enter 1,2,3,4, or 5! Please try again.");
        choice = modeChooser();
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Using a recursive method seems a little overkill here and you could avoid the exception catching part by using the `hasNextInt` provided by Scanner. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `kb.NextInt()` fails the data in the input stream remains, you need to skip past it. If you don't skip the invalid data the loop will continuously try, and fail, to read the invalid input resulting in an infinite loop.

You can use `kb.next()` to skip over the invalid input:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        choice = kb.nextInt();  
        if(choice >= 1 && choice <= 5) break;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        kb.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(choice >= 1 && choice <= 5)
    break;
else
    choice = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use the `Scanner.nextLine()` and `Integer.parseInt()` methods:

```
while(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
    try {
        choice = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());  
    } catch (Exception e) { 
       //...print error msg
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you think it is better not to use the methods provided by Scanner...

Comment: @assylias: I think it depends on the OP's requirement, what if user enters `1 2` (that could be valid/invalid).